# How can i update table with new data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

it is a part of my react js project. First of all, i would like to say that i am new in reactjs. I would like to insert new data to the table but it is not working. i searched a lot in the internet to get any help but all of them was not solved my problem!. First code data is working and showing on the table. I try to get data from value "name and accountable" and push it to the table. If you know how it can be solved please share you thought.

Thank you

```
let row = [{id:1,value1:"jhon",value2:"wills"}]
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [accountable, setAccountable] = useState("");
    

const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID' },
    { field: 'value1', headerName: 'Value1', width: "250"},
    { field: 'value2', headerName: 'Value2' },]

const setTable = () => {
    row = [
        {
            id: 1,
            value1: name,
            value2: accountable
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            value1: name,
            value2: accountable
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            value1: name,
            value2: accountable
        },
    ]
    console.log(row[0]);
}



return (

    <>
        <button onClick={handleShow} className='my' style={{ width: "130px", color: "white" }}><AddIcon style={{ fontSize: "large", textAlign: "center" }} /> New task</button>

        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} size='lg'>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>New task details</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <div className="top">
                    <h6>Last transaction</h6>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <label style={{ fontSize: "14px", color: "purple" }}>Task name</label>
                            <InputGroup size="sm" className="mb-3">
                                <Form.Control
                                    aria-label="Small"
                                    aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                                    value={name}
                                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </InputGroup>
                            {name}
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <label style={{ fontSize: "14px", color: "purple" }}>Accountable</label>
                            <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example" size='sm' value={accountable} onChange={(e) => setAccountable(e.target.value)}>
                                <option value="1">Person 1</option>
                                <option value="2">Person 2</option>
                                <option value="3">Person 3</option>
                            </Form.Select>
                            {accountable}
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <Button variant="success" size='sm' type="submit" style={{ width: "100px", marginTop: "24px" }} onClick={(e) => setTable()}>Add</Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div className="bottom">
                    <h6>Historical transactions</h6>

                    <div className='datatable' style={{ height: "400", width: '100%' }}>
                        <DataGrid style={{ height: "70vh", width: '100%', textAlign: "center" }}
                            rows={row}
                            columns={columns}
                            pageSize={10}
                            rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
                            checkboxSelection
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                    Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                    Save Changes
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    </>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like that could do the job :

```js
// Here is my variable
const [table, setTable] = [1, 2] //This is the default value

// I create a function to add content to my table
function addElement(value) {
    setTable = table.push(value);
}

// In you front-end you need a way to call the method and giving it a value.
// Or you can get the value directly in the method (document.getElement...)
return (
    <button onclick={ addElement(3) }></button>
)
```

Hope it helps, good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I tied to add template data when button is clicked. In the table, I took row variable to add data to my table. But it s not worked.